# Cant enable bluetooth on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

First time Linux user, just installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on an old Satellite L510 (model No. PSLF2A 01U00R)
In settings I can't turn the Bluetooth slider to 'on'. 
"No Bluetooth found, plug in a dongle to use bluetooth".
A wireless mouse does work with a dongle but a wireless Logitech K380 keyboard is not recognised (doesnt come with dongle).
Specs for this laptop specify Bluetooth 2.1
Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
familypc@familypc-Satellite-L510:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8198 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8187B Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b120 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I don't see any bluetooth adapters. Why do you think you have it?

Comment: Actually, you're right, I was looking at specs of a different variant. Thanks.